# Hex to 2's complement decimal?

Tags: assembly, hex, decimal, twos-complement

Each of these 16-bit words can be interpreted as either a 2’s complement number or an unsigned number. Find the decimal integer that corresponds to each interpretation.

A) `00 A3`

B) `B6 4A`

Okay I'm getting a little confused on the wording here. A = `163` and B = `46,666` in decimal notation, but is that an unsigned number or the result 2's complement? I believe it's an unsigned number. To get the 2's complement, would I just have to put it into binary form? If possible, I'd love to see an example.

Comment: there are only 9's complement and 10's complement in decimal, no 2's complement

Answer (score 1):

The hex number 0x876 can be considered a positive number 2166 in decimal.  But if you consider it to be a signed 12 bit number, the msbit is set, so it is negative. To figure out what the decimal number is, you need to do the invert and add one. Inverting yields 0x789, add one 0x78A which is 1930. So, the decimal representation for that as a negative number (two's complement) is -1930.

Take an even easier one the twelve bit number 0xFFF, unsigned that is 4095, but signed that is invert to 0x000 add one 0x001, -1 in decimal.

Apply that knowledge to the numbers in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what he's getting at.

You are correct with the biz "`...A=163 B=46,666 in decimal notation...`"

That is the unsigned 16 bit interpretation.

If these were **signed** 16 bit integers, the first one would still be `163`, while the second one would be `negative 18,870`

What they are getting at is that the top bit is the sign bit, which alerts you to the fact that this could be a negative number.

So, the answer is...

- **For unsigned numbers:** as you have stated, `A=163,  B=46,666`
- **For signed numbers:** as I have stated. `A=163,  B=-18,870`  (note, the last one is negative)

If you need me to go into more detail about this, I'll edit this answer and show you the procedure for doing all the change-o-matic steps in two's complement. In fact, I just did this three hours ago in [THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749653/doubleword-length-2-s-complement-representation-of-binary-number/25750316#25750316) here.  (Click on it if you need to)

Comment: If you could go into more detail here it'd be awesome. How do you tell if a number is signed or unsigned?

Comment: Let's take this to chat

Answer (score 1):

Let us start from the basics:

- Two's complement operation means inverting a binary number and adding 1 to it.
- A number is negative, in two's complement notation, if the highest bit of a binary number is 1
- A number is positive, in two's complement notation, if the highest bit of a binary number is 0
- Using the two's complement operation on a binary number that is already in two's complement notation yields a value equal to its opposite sign.

Therefore, we can deduce, as unsigned numbers, that `A = 163` and `B = 46,666` in decimal. However, signed numbers (two's complement notation) are more difficult to convert. Here, `A = 163` and `B = -18,870`. When converted to binary, you can see that...

```
A = 0000 0000 1010 0011
B = 1011 0110 0100 1010
```

As you can see, the highest order bit of `A` is 0, and the highest order bit of `B` is 1. The highest bit in `A` is 0, so we simply convert as we would for an unsigned number. Since the highest bit of `B` is 1, we need to use the two's complement operation to get the positive version of the binary number, convert to decimal, and prepend a negative sign to the decimal number.

The conversion process is as follows:

```
    1011 0110 0100 1010
```

invert...

```
    0100 1001 1011 0101
```

add 1...

```
    0100 1001 1011 0110
```

convert to decimal...

```
    18870
```

prepend negative sign...

```
    -18870
```

**Note: This is a practical way to convert signed binary numbers to decimal. There are others that can be found on the internet.**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

16 bit: 0000 0000  0000 0000

```
0001 = 1
0010 = 2
0011 = 3
0100 = 4
0101 = 5
0110 = 6
0111 = 7
1000 = 8
1001 = 9
1010 = A
1011 = B
1100 = C
1101 = D
1110 = E
1111 = F
```

Answer (score 0):

A) 00 A3

B) B6 4A

**hex form of A is 00 A3**

For 1s complement:

```
                F F F F
             -  0 0 A 3
                =======
                F F 5 C
```

two's complement

```
              F F 5 C
           +        1
              =======
              F F 5 D
```

---

**hex form of b is B64A**

For 1s complement

```
                F F F F
             -  B 6 4 A
                =======
                4 9 B 5
```

two's complement

```
              4 9 B 5
           +        1
              =======
              4 9 B 6
```

Comment: If you're going to subtract, just subtract from 0 directly (with normal base2 arithmetic).  The point of the one's complement inverse is that you can get it by flipping all the bits without any carry between bits.  i.e. `~0x00A3`.  Doing it with subtraction from 0xFFFF (one's complement negative zero) is completely pointless.